# Blazor server component isn't rerendered

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server (.NETv5) application with a search page.
On this page I have a form to search by name.
On the form submit event I call the search method of my child component.
That component is doing the actual search. This is working fine.
Because the search might take a few seconds I want to show a spinner when the search starts and hide it when the search is done.
Also when I do a second search I want to hide the previous search results.
Hiding the spinner and showing the search results is working, but showing the spinner before the search doesn't work. The variable is set correctly but the page is not rerendered (I think).

My page:

```html
<div class="container pt-2 mb-3">
    <RadzenTemplateForm Data="@searchTerms" Submit="@((SearchTerms args) => { Submit(args); })">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-2 col-6 pl-0">
                <RadzenLabel Text="Name" />
                <RadzenTextBox class="col-12" Name="Name" @bind-Value="searchTerms.Name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
                <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Icon="search" Text="Search" Disabled="@isSearching" />
                <RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Icon="cancel" Text="Cancel" Click="@Cancel" class="ml-2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </RadzenTemplateForm>
</div>

<SearchResultsComponent @ref="searchResultsComponent" />
```

```cs
protected SearchTerms searchTerms = new();
protected SearchResultsComponent searchResultsComponent;
protected bool isSearching;

protected void Submit(SearchTerms args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)) return;
    
    // Disable submit button ==> NOT WORKING:
    isSearching = true;
    // Call search method on child component
    searchResultsComponent.Search(args);
    // Enable submit button again:
    isSearching = false;
}

protected void Cancel()
{
    // Reset form:
    searchTerms = new SearchTerms();
}
```

My child component:

```html
<div class="container">

    @if (isSearching)
    {
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary mr-2" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Searching...</span>
        </div>
        <b>Searching ...</b>
    }

    @if (noResults)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
           No results.
        </div>
    }

    @if (getSearchResults != null && getSearchResults.Any())
    {
        <RadzenHeading Size="H2" Text=@($"Results({getSearchResults.Count})")></RadzenHeading>
        <div class="row">

            @foreach (var searchResult in getSearchResults)
            {
                <RadzenCard>
                    <b>@searchResult.Name</b>
                </RadzenCard>
            }

        </div>
    }

</div>
```

```cs
private IList<MultiShardSearchResultsWerknemer> _searchResults;
private bool _isSearching = true;
private bool _noResults;

protected bool noResults
{
    get => _noResults;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_noResults, value)) return;
        _noResults = value;
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}        

protected bool isSearching
{
    get => _isSearching;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_isSearching, value)) return;
        _isSearching = value;
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}

protected IList<MultiShardSearchResultsWerknemer> getSearchResults
{
    get => _searchResults;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_searchResults, value)) return;
        _searchResults = value;
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}

public void Search(SearchTerms args)
{
    Helpers.ConsoleLog(args);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)) return;
    
    // Reset ==> NOT WORKING:
    isSearching = true;
    noResults = false;
    getSearchResults = null;
    InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());

    getSearchResults = ShardingService.SearchForAllEmployees(args.Name, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Helpers.ConsoleLog("Found results: " + getSearchResults.Count);
    isSearching = false;
    noResults = !getSearchResults.Any();
}
```

For debugging purposes, I've set `_isSearching = true` which shows me the spinner. The spinner is also hidden when the search is done, so that is working. But I can't get the spinner to show when I start searching.
I've tried all options I could find, without success.
I must be missing something. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your search handel method

```
protected void Submit(SearchTerms args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)) return;
    
    // Disable submit button ==> NOT WORKING:
    isSearching = true;
    // Call search method on child component
    searchResultsComponent.Search(args);
    // Enable submit button again:
    isSearching = false;
}
```

Keep in mind, that rendering will occur once the method has finished. So, before the call `isSearching`  is `false` and after it is also `false`. That's why you don't see the spinner.

Blazor offers a method to kick off a new render cycle: `StateHasChanged()`.

So, you could modify your submit method like

```
protected void Submit(SearchTerms args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)) return;
    
    isSearching = true;
    StateHasChanged()

    // Call search method on child component
    searchResultsComponent.Search(args);

    isSearching = false;
    StateHasChanged()
}
```

So, you click the search/submit button on this method is executed.

Or if you like, create a property instead

```
@code
{
    private Boolean isSearching = false;

    public Boolean IsSearching
    {
        get => isSearching;
        private set
        {
            isSearching = value;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void Submit(SearchTerms args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)) return;

        IsSearching = true;

        // Call search method on child component
        searchResultsComponent.Search(args);

        IsSearching = false;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it but faced a similar problems once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As you can see in my post I already have a property and am calling `StateHasChanged()` in the property and also tried calling it on other locations but still the spinner isn't shown.

Comment: My apologies.I really haven't seen it.